# Custom filter only works for certain name jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

so I tried using custom filter in jinja2 and flask
so here is the problem:

this is the html file

```
<h1>Hello, {{ user.nickname | reverse }}!</h1>
```

and this is the py file

```
from app import app

def reverse_filter(s):
    return s[::-1]


app.jinja_env.filters['reverse'] = reverse_filter
```

the code above is working fine. But now if I change the name 'reverse' into e.g.'mouse'

```
<h1>Hello, {{ user.nickname | mouse }}!</h1>
```

then the new py

```
from app import app

def mouse_filter(s):
    return s[::-1]


app.jinja_env.filters['mouse'] = mouse_filter
```

it will give me `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'mouse'`

It is really weird... did I do something wrong?

Comment: `reverse` is already a [built-in filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#reverse), that's why it worked. You must have a problem with your filter registration.

Comment: ah thought so... Have no idea where toe problem is. I have tried using @app.template_filter() and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the mistake, 
I put my filter in separate file (`jinja_custom_filter.py`) from my `__init__.py` file so I need to put

`from app import jinja_custom_filter.py` in my `init` file to be able to use it.

Still don't really understand why I need to put every reference file in `__init__.py` though